# C++, Проблема в методе

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, методы

Ошибка где-то здесь:

```
class Array
{
    int size;
    int* ar;
  public:
    Array(int _size): size(_size), ar(NULL)
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            ar = new int[size];
        }
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        if (ar)
        {
            delete[]ar;
        }
    }
    int* GetArray() const
    {
        return ar;
    }
    int GetSize() const
    {
        return size;
    }

    void show()
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                cout << *(ar + i);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Студия выдает:

2x:

> *C3867    'Array::GetArray': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member.*

Вызов:

```
Array p(a);
for (int i = 0;i < p.GetSize();i++) {
    p.GetArray[i] = 0;
}
cout << endl;
p.show;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут

```
p.GetArray[i] = 0;
```

вы забыли **вызвать** функцию:

```
p.GetArray()[i] = 0;
```

У вас получился указатель на метод, а не указатель на `int`.

Comment: Спасибо, еще нужно в p.show()

Comment: А, да, но я смотрел только на то сообщение об ошибке, что вы привели, и на него и ответил.

Comment: Если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый...